# How do I stop my program from printing "Try again" so many times?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int whatcube(int y);

int main(){
    int y;
    cout << "Enter a perfect cube:";
    cin >> y;
    cout << whatcube(y);

    return 0;
}

int whatcube(int y){
    for(int i=1;i<=y; i++){
        if(i*i*i==y){
            cout <<  "This is a perfect cube!";
        }
        else 
        cout << "Try Again.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have very basic knowledge of coding but I want this function to print "Try Again" once if it is not a perfect cube. When the user inputs 8 for example, "Try again" appears 8 times. I also dont know why there is a zero at the end.

Comment: Discuss the purpose of the `for` loop with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
int whatcube(int y){
    for(int i=1;i<=y; i++){
        if(i*i*i==y){
            cout <<  "This is a perfect cube!";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "Try again.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked but how do I stop it from printing "0" at the end?

Comment: It's printing the return value of your function. Your function returns an integer value (indicated by the int in front of whatcube). Instead of doing cout << whatcube(y), just do whatcube(y)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int whatcube(int y){
    for(int i=1;i<=y; i++){
        if(i*i*i==y){
            std::cout <<  "This is a perfect cube!";
        }
        else 
           std::cout << "Try Again.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will print "Try Again." when `i` is not the 3rd root of `y` in the loop, which is probably not what you want.

Also, your `whatcube()` returns an `int`, which will always `return 0;` because you code it like that. You print that return value, so it will print a zero. Looking at your code, you should make `whatcube()` a `void` function.

So, change your forward declaration to:

```cpp
void whatcube(int y);
```

Your `whatcube()` function should be like this:

```cpp
void whatcube(int y){
    for(int i = 1; i * i * i <= y; i++){ // i * i * i <= y; for optimization
        if(i * i * i == y){
            std::cout <<  "This is a perfect cube!";
            return;
        }
          
    }
    std::cout << "Try Again.";
}
```

And call your `main()` function like this:

```cpp
int main(){
    int y;
    std::cout << "Enter a perfect cube:";
    std::cin >> y;
    whatcube(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get your program to stop printing "Try again." by revising your instructions to be more specific and precise.
Your program is working exactly as designed. I would estimate that it prints out "Try again." *approximately* a number of times equal to the user input.

Listing what you've done well:

- Forward declaration of your `whatcube` function
- Declaring int i in your `for` loop
- Incrementing i once per cycle of your `for` loop

It is printing out zero at the end because you've told it to, specifically and explicitly.

In addition to the 'rubber duck' method mentioned above, I would recommend mentally walking through each step, each instruction, just as if you were the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing last '0' because on your main you have this line

cout << whatcube(y);

And you are printing many times because you have

```
std::cout <<  "This is a perfect cube!";
```

inside your **for** statement.

You can optimize your code not testing numbers whose cube is greater than **y** inside your whatcube(y) function. And it will be useful to use return value to get some information, not always 0 i.e 0 if is a perfect cube, -1 if not.

```
int whatcube(int y){
    int num=0;
    int cube=0;
    while (cube<y){
        ++num;
        cube=num*num*num;
    };

    if(cube==y)
        cout <<  "This is a perfect cube!";
    else
        cout << "Try Again.";

    return cube==y?0:-1;
}
```